# System unable to find Balanced.js when running eb deploy?

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a node server to Elastic-BeanStalk, and I get this error.

ERROR: WindowsError :: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: './node_modules\restify\node_modules\bunyan\node_modules\mv\node_modules\rimraf\node_modules\glob\node_modules\minimatch\node_modules\brace-expansion\node_modules\balanced-match\test\balanced.js'

I've looked for balanced and it is there. I've been able to deploy with out this error in the past, and I don't think I have made any changes since then.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'r on a windows env in the beanstalk, and maybe not on your dev computer ?

```
./node_modules\restify
```

The / then the \ seems strange to me.